# How to get YouTube Videos Description and Comments with Youtube Api in php

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am working on a YouTube project, in which i am getting data from YouTube by RSS, I am getting title only with RSS, now I want to get description and comments of that specific video. I have tried many methods but none of them is working for me, except one but that is not giving me description and comments it’s just returning me name, height width, video url, author etc
Codes that I tried are given bellow 
This code is working but not returning what I need

```
$youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=". $src_url_r ."&format=json";
$curl = curl_init($youtube);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$tst = json_decode($return, true);
```

Other code that i tried and not working are

```
$id = substr(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rss_pi_source_url', TRUE), strrpos(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rss_pi_source_url', TRUE), '=') + 1);

        //echo "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$id."?v=2&alt=json";
        $json_output = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$src_url."?v=2&alt=json");
        $json = json_decode($json_output, true);

        //This gives you the video description
        $video_description = $json['entry']['media$group']['media$description']['$t'];

        //This gives you the video views count
        $view_count = $json['entry']['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];

        //This gives you the video title
        $video_title = $json['entry']['title']['$t'];
```

this is an other piecec of code that is not working

```
$json_output = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=0KNk-Joi-NM&key=my_api_key");
            $json = json_decode($json_output, true);
            print_r($json);
```

Please any one guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First just put your

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=0KNk-Joi-NM&key=my_api_key
```

in your browser and see if you get the correct response. If you don't see the following with your key, check your key's credentials. Works fine here with my key.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/3EAsCBWH9776A-ORuySfGxdI1go\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/mvwmsHAehTppyzBCqqEpnCIt2d4\"",
   "id": "0KNk-Joi-NM",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-05-19T06:30:28.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCy436qLXlyLqddExVC64auw",
    "title": "Tera Ghata | Gajendra Verma Ft. Karishma Sharma | Vikram Singh | Official Video",
    "description": "Welcome to the Official Channel of Gajendra Verma\nBlive Music & Entertainment and Virtual Planet Present #GajendraVerma New Music Video #TeraGhata ft. Karishma Sharma Directed by Vikram Singh\n\nHear It Exclusively on Gaana : https://gaana.com/song/tera-ghata\nDownload Link : \n\nOperator Codes:\nAirtel Subscribers Dial 009165300001618\nAirtel Subscribers Dial 5432116531618\nVodafone Subscribers sms CT 10472118 to 56789\nVodafone Subscribers Dial 53710472118\nIdea Subscribers Dial 5678910472118\nDocomo Promo Code for Call Me Tunes sms SET 10472118 to 543211\nBSNL (N) NORTH Subscribers ZONE BT 7092421 to 56700\nBSNL (W) WEST Subscribers ZONE BT 7092421 to 56700\nBSNL (S) SOUTH Subscribers ZONE BT 10472118 to 56700\nBSNL (E) EAST Subscribers ZONE BT 10472118 to 56700\nVirgin Subscribers SMS 10472118 to 58475\nTelenor OnMobile Subscribers SMS ACT 10472118 to 543211\n\nSong: Tera Ghata\nAlbum: From Lost To Found\nSinger/Composer/Lyricist: Gajendra Verma\nLyricist: Gajendra Verma\n\nDirected by: Vikram Singh \nProducer: Sanjay Kukreja\nStarring : Karishma Sharma\nProduction: Virtual Planet Production\nCinematographer: Suman Dutta\nAssistant Director: Mansi Moghe, Vishal Yoman, Rohan Shah\nEditor: Hashtag# Studios\nColorist: Vikrant Studios (Nirmal Sharma)\nPublicity Design : Kalpanik Films\nMakeup & Hair: Aanchal Khanna\nStylist: Surubhi Sharma\nSocial Promotion: Ayushi Anand\nFocus Puller: Ramu Karri\nDrone: Aditya Pandey\nCamera Team: Vikas Jaiswal, Avishekh Patel\nLine Production: Destination Siam, Thailand, Emerald Cove\nOnline Promotions : Chitransh Jain & Shubham Jain\nRecord Label: Virtual Planet Music\n\n♫Social Handle ♫\nConnect with Gajendra Verma:\nFacebook /iVermaGajendra\nInstagram @iVermaGajendra\nTwitter @iVermaGajendra\n\nSubscribe for More Videos\nSubscribe: \nFacebook: http://www.facebook.com/virtualplanetmusic\nGoogle: http://www.google.com/+virtualplanetmusic\n\nWebsite\nhttp://www.virtualplanet.in\n\nFor Live Shows Bookings & Business Enquiries: \nPrashant Chaudhary +919988989833.\nPrashant Chaudhary +919988989833.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0KNk-Joi-NM/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0KNk-Joi-NM/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0KNk-Joi-NM/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0KNk-Joi-NM/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0KNk-Joi-NM/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Gajendra Verma",
    "tags": [
     "Gajendra verma",
     "Gajendra verma songs",
     "Vikram Singh",
     "Gajendra verma Official",
     "Virtual Planet Music",
     "tera ghata",
     "tera",
     "ghata",
     "karishma sharma",
     "gajendra verma",
     "gajendra verma song",
     "gajendra verma all songs",
     "gajendra verma new song",
     "karishma sharma song",
     "latest bollywood songs",
     "gajendra verma songs",
     "latest hindi songs",
     "viral song",
     "tera ghata mera kuch nahi jata",
     "tera ghata viral video",
     "isme tera ghata mera kuch nahi jata",
     "isme tera ghata viral video"
    ],
    "categoryId": "10",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Tera Ghata | Gajendra Verma Ft. Karishma Sharma | Vikram Singh | Official Video",
     "description": "Welcome to the Official Channel of Gajendra Verma\nBlive Music & Entertainment and Virtual Planet Present #GajendraVerma New Music Video #TeraGhata ft. Karishma Sharma Directed by Vikram Singh\n\nHear It Exclusively on Gaana : https://gaana.com/song/tera-ghata\nDownload Link : \n\nOperator Codes:\nAirtel Subscribers Dial 009165300001618\nAirtel Subscribers Dial 5432116531618\nVodafone Subscribers sms CT 10472118 to 56789\nVodafone Subscribers Dial 53710472118\nIdea Subscribers Dial 5678910472118\nDocomo Promo Code for Call Me Tunes sms SET 10472118 to 543211\nBSNL (N) NORTH Subscribers ZONE BT 7092421 to 56700\nBSNL (W) WEST Subscribers ZONE BT 7092421 to 56700\nBSNL (S) SOUTH Subscribers ZONE BT 10472118 to 56700\nBSNL (E) EAST Subscribers ZONE BT 10472118 to 56700\nVirgin Subscribers SMS 10472118 to 58475\nTelenor OnMobile Subscribers SMS ACT 10472118 to 543211\n\nSong: Tera Ghata\nAlbum: From Lost To Found\nSinger/Composer/Lyricist: Gajendra Verma\nLyricist: Gajendra Verma\n\nDirected by: Vikram Singh \nProducer: Sanjay Kukreja\nStarring : Karishma Sharma\nProduction: Virtual Planet Production\nCinematographer: Suman Dutta\nAssistant Director: Mansi Moghe, Vishal Yoman, Rohan Shah\nEditor: Hashtag# Studios\nColorist: Vikrant Studios (Nirmal Sharma)\nPublicity Design : Kalpanik Films\nMakeup & Hair: Aanchal Khanna\nStylist: Surubhi Sharma\nSocial Promotion: Ayushi Anand\nFocus Puller: Ramu Karri\nDrone: Aditya Pandey\nCamera Team: Vikas Jaiswal, Avishekh Patel\nLine Production: Destination Siam, Thailand, Emerald Cove\nOnline Promotions : Chitransh Jain & Shubham Jain\nRecord Label: Virtual Planet Music\n\n♫Social Handle ♫\nConnect with Gajendra Verma:\nFacebook /iVermaGajendra\nInstagram @iVermaGajendra\nTwitter @iVermaGajendra\n\nSubscribe for More Videos\nSubscribe: \nFacebook: http://www.facebook.com/virtualplanetmusic\nGoogle: http://www.google.com/+virtualplanetmusic\n\nWebsite\nhttp://www.virtualplanet.in\n\nFor Live Shows Bookings & Business Enquiries: \nPrashant Chaudhary +919988989833.\nPrashant Chaudhary +919988989833."
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```